# NoSQL DB written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, nosql

Was curious, but are any NoSQL DBMS written in Ruby?

And if not, would it be unwise to create one in Ruby?

Comment: There is ruby bindings for MongoDB btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was curious, but are any NoSQL DBMS written in Ruby?

In 2007, [Anthony Eden](http://AnthonyEden.Com/) played around with [RDDB](http://RDDB.RubyForge.Org/), a CouchDB-inspired document-oriented database. He still keeps [a copy of the code](https://GitHub.Com/AEden/RDDB/) in his GitHub account.

I vaguely remember that at or around the same time, someone else was also playing around with a database in Ruby. I think it was either inspired by or a reaction to RDDB.

Last but not least, there is the [PStore library](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/pstore/frames/) in the stdlib, which – depending on your definition – may or may not count as a database.

> And if not, would it be unwise to create one in Ruby?

The biggest problem I see in Ruby are its concurrency primitives. Threads and locks are *so* 1960s. If you want to support multiple concurrent users, then you obviously need concurrency, although if you want to build an embedded in-process database, then this is much less of a concern.

Other than that, there are some not-so-stellar implementations of Ruby, but that is not a limitation of Ruby but of those particular implementations, and it applies to pretty much every other programming language as well. Rubinius (especially the current development trunk, which adds Ruby 1.9 compatibility and removes the Global Interpreter Lock) and JRuby would both be fine choices.

As an added bonus, Rubinius comes with a built-in actors library for concurrency and JRuby gives you access to e.g. Clojure's concurrency libraries or the Akka actors library.

Performance isn't really much of a concern, I think. Rubinius's `Hash` class, which is written in 100% pure Ruby, performs comparably to YARV's `Hash` class, which is written in 100% hand-optimized C. This shows you that Ruby code, at least when it is carefully written, can be just as fast as C, especially since databases tend to be long-running and thus Rubinius's or JRuby's (and in the latter case specifically also the JVM's) dynamic optimizers (which C compilers typically do *not* have) can *really* get to work.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is just too slow for any type of  DBMS

c/c++/erlang are generally the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't care in what programming language was a DBMS implemented as long it has all the features and is available for use from your application programming language of choice.

So, the real question here is do you need one written in Ruby or available for use in Ruby.

In first case, I doubt you'll find a DBMS *natively* written in Ruby (any correction of this statement will be appreciated).

In second case, you should be able to find Ruby bindings/wrappers for any decent DBMS relational or not.

Comment: Agree with Goran. Most Databases have a ruby binding/wrapper available. There are several Ruby bindings for SQL/Relational databases. There are also non-SQL bindings available. For example, there are several Ruby bindings for Berkeley DB's key/value pair API. A recent one can be found here: https://github.com/mattbauer/bdb